# Trying to get the Signal to Noise Ratio for X-ray spectrum

Tags: astronomy, x-rays

I am new to this forum so forgive me if the question is too trivial.

Here is the problem: I have an x-ray spectrum of a galaxy and there are some emission lines in it. All I have to do is find a good fit to the spectrum, and get the Signal to Noise ratio. I have used sherpa for this, have used the power-law to fit the continuum and a Gaussian at the peak value, and have a decent fit. I can also directly find the equivalent width of the emission line(using the eqwidth() function), and want to find the Signal/Noise ratio of the emission peak? I am using XMM-Newton data.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: What will you do with the number once you have it? There are different ways to define SNR - it would be helpful to understand what you need it for.

Comment: I want to find out how significant the emission line is. Is the line due to a random noise fluctuation or due to some element/ion.